# CUDAのNVCCでコマンドプロンプトでコンパイルしたいのですがエラーが出てきます。

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu

環境は
Windows10  （64bit）
CUDA  9.1

こちらがソースコードです

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp>
#include <ocvlibs.h>

using namespace cv;

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
//main
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try
    {
        int wait = 1;
        int numOfGpu = gpu::getCudaEnabledDeviceCount();

        if (numOfGpu <= 0)
            throw ("no Gpu available.");

        VideoCapture capture;

        if (argc == 2)
        {
            capture = VideoCapture(argv[1]);
            wait = 33;
        }
        else
            capture = VideoCapture(0);

        const char* wName = "dst";
        Mat src, dst;
        gpu::GpuMat gpuSrc, gpuDst;
        namedWindow(wName, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

        while (true)
        {
            capture >> src;
            if (src.empty()) break;

            gpuSrc.upload(src);
            gpu::cvtColor(gpuSrc, gpuDst, COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
            gpuDst.download(dst);

            imshow(wName, dst);

            if (waitKey(wait) >= 0) break;
        }
    }
    catch (const char* str)
    {
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
    }
    catch (const cv::Exception* ex)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: " << ex->what() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

ヘッダファイルは特有のものなのでこちらに載せます。

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifdef _DEBUG                                   //Debugモードの場合
    #pragma comment(lib,"opencv_calib3d246d.lib")
    #pragma comment(lib,"opencv_core246d.lib")
    #pragma comment(lib,"opencv_contrib246d.lib")
    #pragma comment(lib,"opencv_features2d246d.lib")
    #pragma comment(lib,"opencv_flann246d.lib")
    #pragma comment(lib,"opencv_gpu246d.lib")
    #pragma comment(lib,"opencv_haartraining_engined.lib")
    #pragma comment(lib,"opencv_highgui246d.lib")
    #pragma comment(lib,"opencv_imgproc246d.lib")
    #pragma comment(lib,"opencv_legacy246d.lib")
    #pragma comment(lib,"opencv_ml246d.lib")
    #pragma comment(lib,"opencv_objdetect246d.lib")
    #pragma comment(lib,"opencv_ts246d.lib")
    #pragma comment(lib,"opencv_video246d.lib")
#else                                           //Releaseモードの場合
    #pragma comment(lib,"opencv_calib3d246.lib")
    #pragma comment(lib,"opencv_core246.lib")
    #pragma comment(lib,"opencv_contrib246.lib")
    #pragma comment(lib,"opencv_features2d246.lib")
    #pragma comment(lib,"opencv_flann246.lib")
    #pragma comment(lib,"opencv_gpu246.lib")
    #pragma comment(lib,"opencv_haartraining_engine.lib")
    #pragma comment(lib,"opencv_highgui246.lib")
    #pragma comment(lib,"opencv_imgproc246.lib")
    #pragma comment(lib,"opencv_legacy246.lib")
    #pragma comment(lib,"opencv_ml246.lib")
    #pragma comment(lib,"opencv_objdetect246.lib")
    #pragma comment(lib,"opencv_ts246.lib")
    #pragma comment(lib,"opencv_video246.lib")
#endif
```

こちらがエラーになります。

```
GPUGPU.cu
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.1\bin/../include\cuda_runtime.h: warning C4819: ファイルは、現在のコード ページ (932) で表示できない文字を含んでいます。データの損失を防ぐために、ファイルを Unicode 形式で保存してくださ い。
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.1\bin/../include\w32api.h(186): warning C4005: '_EXTERN_C': マクロが再定義されました。
C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/../../VC/INCLUDE\yvals.h(560): note: '_EXTERN_C' の以前の定義を確認してください
c:\program files\nvidia gpu computing toolkit\cuda\v9.1\include\cuda_runtime_api.h(1950): warning C4819: ファイルは、現 在のコード ページ (932) で表示できない文字を含んでいます。データの損失を防ぐために、ファイルを Unicode 形式で保存してく ださい。
c:\program files\nvidia gpu computing toolkit\cuda\v9.1\include\cuda_runtime_api.h(1950): warning C4819: ファイルは、現 在のコード ページ (932) で表示できない文字を含んでいます。データの損失を防ぐために、ファイルを Unicode 形式で保存してく ださい。
c:\program files\nvidia gpu computing toolkit\cuda\v9.1\include\crt\math_functions.h: warning C4819: ファイルは、現在の コード ページ (932) で表示できない文字を含んでいます。データの損失を防ぐために、ファイルを Unicode 形式で保存してくださ い。
c:\program files\nvidia gpu computing toolkit\cuda\v9.1\include\crt\math_functions.h(838): warning C4819: ファイルは、現在のコード ページ (932) で表示できない文字を含んでいます。データの損失を防ぐために、ファイルを Unicode 形式で保存してく ださい。
c:\program files\nvidia gpu computing toolkit\cuda\v9.1\include\crt\math_functions.h(1772): warning C4819: ファイルは、 現在のコード ページ (932) で表示できない文字を含んでいます。データの損失を防ぐために、ファイルを Unicode 形式で保存して ください。
c:\program files\nvidia gpu computing toolkit\cuda\v9.1\include\crt\math_functions.h(2628): warning C4819: ファイルは、 現在のコード ページ (932) で表示できない文字を含んでいます。データの損失を防ぐために、ファイルを Unicode 形式で保存して ください。
c:\program files\nvidia gpu computing toolkit\cuda\v9.1\include\crt\math_functions.h(3477): warning C4819: ファイルは、 現在のコード ページ (932) で表示できない文字を含んでいます。データの損失を防ぐために、ファイルを Unicode 形式で保存して ください。
c:\program files\nvidia gpu computing toolkit\cuda\v9.1\include\crt\math_functions.h(4417): warning C4819: ファイルは、 現在のコード ページ (932) で表示できない文字を含んでいます。データの損失を防ぐために、ファイルを Unicode 形式で保存して ください。
c:\program files\nvidia gpu computing toolkit\cuda\v9.1\include\crt\math_functions.h(5319): warning C4819: ファイルは、 現在のコード ページ (932) で表示できない文字を含んでいます。データの損失を防ぐために、ファイルを Unicode 形式で保存して ください。
c:\program files\nvidia gpu computing toolkit\cuda\v9.1\include\crt\math_functions.h(6229): warning C4819: ファイルは、 現在のコード ページ (932) で表示できない文字を含んでいます。データの損失を防ぐために、ファイルを Unicode 形式で保存して ください。
c:\program files\nvidia gpu computing toolkit\cuda\v9.1\include\crt\math_functions.h(7104): warning C4819: ファイルは、 現在のコード ページ (932) で表示できない文字を含んでいます。データの損失を防ぐために、ファイルを Unicode 形式で保存して ください。
c:\program files\nvidia gpu computing toolkit\cuda\v9.1\include\crt\math_functions.h(7914): warning C4819: ファイルは、 現在のコード ページ (932) で表示できない文字を含んでいます。データの損失を防ぐために、ファイルを Unicode 形式で保存して ください。
c:\program files\nvidia gpu computing toolkit\cuda\v9.1\include\crt/device_functions.h: warning C4819: ファイルは、現在 のコード ページ (932) で表示できない文字を含んでいます。データの損失を防ぐために、ファイルを Unicode 形式で保存してくだ さい。
c:\program files\nvidia gpu computing toolkit\cuda\v9.1\include\crt/device_functions.h(776): warning C4819: ファイルは、現在のコード ページ (932) で表示できない文字を含んでいます。データの損失を防ぐために、ファイルを Unicode 形式で保存して ください。
c:\program files\nvidia gpu computing toolkit\cuda\v9.1\include\crt/device_functions.h(1636): warning C4819: ファイルは 、現在のコード ページ (932) で表示できない文字を含んでいます。データの損失を防ぐために、ファイルを Unicode 形式で保存し てください。
c:\program files\nvidia gpu computing toolkit\cuda\v9.1\include\crt\device_double_functions.h: warning C4819: ファイルは、現在のコード ページ (932) で表示できない文字を含んでいます。データの損失を防ぐために、ファイルを Unicode 形式で保存し てください。
c:\program files\nvidia gpu computing toolkit\cuda\v9.1\include\sm_20_intrinsics.h: warning C4819: ファイルは、現在のコ ード ページ (932) で表示できない文字を含んでいます。データの損失を防ぐために、ファイルを Unicode 形式で保存してください 。
c:\program files\nvidia gpu computing toolkit\cuda\v9.1\include\sm_20_intrinsics.h(925): warning C4819: ファイルは、現在のコード ページ (932) で表示できない文字を含んでいます。データの損失を防ぐために、ファイルを Unicode 形式で保存してくだ さい。
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.1\bin/../include\float.h(57): fatal error C1021: プリプロセッサ コマンド 'include_next' が無効です。
```

ヘッダファイルはちゃんと読み込めているはずなのにエラーが出る理由がいまいちわかりません。
なぜこのようなエラーが出るのでしょうか？
どうか解決のためにお力を貸していただけないでしょうか？

Answer (score 3):

nvccはCUDAのカーネルコード（GPU用デバイスコード）をコンパイルし、CPU用ホストコードとの連結部分（ディスパッチャー）を自動生成するための特殊なコンパイラーです。nvcc単独では意味をなしません。
CPU用ホストコードは、nvccが寄生する**ホストコンパイラー**に渡されてコンパイルされます。Windows環境では通例ホストコンパイラーとしてVisual C++ (cl.exe) が使われます。
ホスト環境は何を使っていますか？（Visual Studioのバージョンはいくつですか？）
本来`#include_next`はGCC固有のプリプロセッサなので、おそらくnvccとホストコンパイラーの連携が正しく構成されていないことが原因です。

しかし、そもそもnvccを使いたい理由は何ですか？

見たところ、単にOpenCV 2.4.6のgpuモジュールを使っているだけのようなので、nvccを使う必要はまったくないはずです。普通に`.cpp`としてコンパイルすべきコードのはずです。
また、基本的にコマンドラインでnvccを使う必要はなく、通例CUDA Toolkitと同時にインストールされる**Visual Studioインテグレーション**を使えば、Visual C++プロジェクト中の`.cu`ファイルはnvccを使ってコンパイルされるようになります。CUDA入門者は通例CUDAコンソールアプリケーションのプロジェクトテンプレートをベースに学習します。また、**CUDA C/C++言語**を使うコードのみを`.cu`に記述し、通常のC/C++関数としてラップして、**CUDA C/C++言語**を使わないコードは`.c`あるいは`.cpp`に記述するのが常套手段です。

なお、C4819はエラーではなく、Visual C++コンパイラーからの警告です。警告を消すために、むやみにファーストパーティ製やサードパーティ製のライブラリヘッダーを書き換えるべきではありません。
もし本当にnvccを使わなければならない（**CUDA C/C++言語**を使わなければならない）場合、Visual C++プロジェクト内の`.cu`ファイルのプロパティにて、
[CUDA C/C++]→[Command Line]→[Additional Options]に
`-Xcompiler "/wd 4819"`
を指定すれば、ライブラリヘッダーを不必要に書き換えることなく、C4819の警告は消せます。

`-Xcompiler`はホストコンパイラーにオプションを渡すときに使用します。詳しくはnvccのマニュアルを参照してください。
http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html

また、CUDA Toolkitのバージョンによって、サポートしているVisual StudioおよびVC++コンパイラーのバージョンは異なります。CUDA Toolkit 9.1がサポートしているのはVisual Studio 2012/2013/2015/2017です。VS2010のサポートはdeprecated (廃止予定) となっています。
http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html

Comment: CUDAを使っている理由はGPUを使いたいためです。GPU高速画像処理という本を参考にしています（https://www.amazon.co.jp/GPU%E9%AB%98%E9%80%9F%E5%8B%95%E7%94%BB%E5%83%8F%E5%87%A6%E7%90%86%E2%80%95OpenCV%E3%81%A7GPU%E3%81%AE%E5%87%A6%E7%90%86%E8%83%BD%E5%8A%9B%E3%82%92%E3%82%88%E3%82%8A%E8%BA%AB%E8%BF%91%E3%81%AB-%E5%8C%97%E5%B1%B1-%E6%B4%8B%E5%B9%B8/dp/4877833307）この本ではNVIDIAのGPUを使う際のプログラムの拡張子がcppとなっているためcuなのではないかと思いながらも進めていました。nvcc単体では使えないことは初めて知りました。あの後文字コードに関する警告は消えたのですが最後の「C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.1\bin/../include\float.h(57): fatal error C1021: プリプロセッサ コマンド 'include_next' が無効です。」というエラーだけがどうにも解決できず進まずにいます。

Comment: ＞＞単にOpenCV 2.4.6のgpuモジュールを使っているだけ　とありますがgpuモジュールとはgpuを使っているのですか？

Comment: どうもありがとうございます。今、拡張子をcppに変更し、g＋＋コマンドでコンパイルしたところ鬼のような警告と最初と最後に二行ほどのエラーメッセージが出力されました。https://pastebin.com/yfnJyuXM

Comment: OpenCVのgpuモジュールの内部ではCUDAが使われており、gpuモジュールのビルドをするためにはCUDA Toolkitが必要です。しかし、単にgpuモジュールを使うアプリケーションでは、CUDAを直接使う必要はなく、またCUDA C/C++言語を使わないのであれば、nvccを使う必要はありません。普通のC/C++プログラムとしてコンパイル＆ビルドすればよいだけです。なお、OpenCV 2.4.7以降のWindows向けビルド済みバイナリでは、OpenCLをバックエンドに使うoclモジュールが標準で有効になっています。一方、gpuモジュールは標準で無効になっており、仮にアプリケーションのコンパイル＆ビルドが通っても実行時に呼び出しが失敗します。gpuモジュールを有効にするには自分でOpenCVをビルドする必要があります。またCUDAはNVIDIA GPU上でしか動作しませんが、OpenCLは様々なプラットフォームおよびハードウェア（CPU/GPU/etc.）をサポートしているので、gpuモジュールよりoclモジュールを使うことを推奨します。

Comment: Windows上でOpenCVを使う場合、g++ (gcc) ではなくVisual C++ (Visual Studio) を使うことを強く推奨します。自己解決できるスキルがない場合、gccは推奨しません。Visual C++からOpenCVを利用する情報はすぐに見つかるはずです。C4819云々から推察するに、すでに何らかのVC++コンパイラーがインストールされているものと思われますが、VS2013/2015/2017には無償のCommunityエディションが用意されており、インストールするだけで学習・開発環境が整います（Visual C++をインストールするには、VSインストーラーのオプションで明示的に選択する必要があります）。あとは自分で調べてください。書籍はすぐに陳腐化するので参考にしないほうがいいです。特に理由がなければ、古いOpenCV 2.xではなく、新しいOpenCV 3.xを使うことを推奨します。なお、まずは従来のCPUベースのOpenCVアプリケーションプログラムを書ける最低限の知識がないと、いきなりoclモジュールに手を出しても挫折する可能性が高いです。

Comment: どうやらOPENCLはNVIDIAでも動くようなのでいったんCUDAからはなれてOPENCLについて調べてみます。どうもありがとうございます。

Comment: では、画像処理で物体検出を行う場合はCUDAよりもOPENCLのほうが並行処理の原理が理解できたり、使いやすいということでしょうか？私は画像処理で物体検出を行ったり機械学習を行いたい為CUDAを使っていました。OPENCLでもそれが可能ならば使ってみたいと思います。

Comment: ちなみに、こちらのサイトのhttps://qiita.com/GRGSIBERIA/items/d8290c1a3ded59f4075aはCUDAではなく、OPENCLでNVIDIAのGPUを使うというものなのでしょうか？

Comment: GPU並列処理のごく基本的な原理を学習する段階では、CUDAもOpenCLも大差はありません。CUDAはNVIDIA専用のため、NVIDIA GPUの能力を最大限活かすことができ、またCUDA C/C++という高度な言語拡張と、cuFFTやcuDNNといった便利なライブラリが公式に用意されているため、アルゴリズム開発に注力しやすくなっています。一方OpenCLの最大のメリットは多様なプラットフォームのサポートにあります。逆にプログラミングおよびチューニングのしやすさの点ではCUDAに劣ります。OpenCV 3.xではOpenCLがT-APIとして統合されており、CUDAよりOpenCLのほうが親和性が高くなります。ただし、CUDAもOpenCLもハードウェアに関する高度な知識がないと扱うことはできません。物体検出は、何をどう検出したいかにもよるでしょうが、少なくとも今どきアプリケーション開発者がCUDAやOpenCLといった下位層を直接叩いてアルゴリズムを構築するようなことはめったにありません。OpenCV 3.xにはCPUベースおよびOpenCLベースのDNNが実装されています。テンプレートマッチングやTensorFlowもあります。あとは自分で調べてください。https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/DNN-Efficiency

Comment: どうもありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

CUDAを使わない方向で話が進んでいそうなので必要ないかもしれませんが、

> warning C4819: ファイルは、現在のコード ページ (932) で表示できない文字を含んでいます。データの損失を防ぐために、ファイルを Unicode 形式で保存してくださ い。

cubickさんはソースコードの保存し直しを、syghさんは`/wd 4819`による警告の抑止を提示されていますが、Visual C++ 2015で追加された[`/source-charset (Set Source Character Set)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt708819.aspx)オプションを設定することをお勧めします。Visual C++ではUnicode対応のため文字コードの解析が必要です（`L""`文字列はソースコードのバイト列そのままでなくUnicodeへ変換します）。BOMが付けられているソースコードには問題ありませんが、付けられていない場合は現在のOSの設定を使用しShift-JIS（codepage 932）であると推測します。国外から入手したソースコードはWindows-1252等が使われていることがあり、その場合はVisual C++であれば

```
/source-charset:.1252
```

もしくはCUDAであれば

```
-Xcompiler "/source-charset:.1252"
```

を指定することでソースコードの文字コードを正しく認識できます。ただし、今度はShift-JISが使えなくなることに注意が必要です。

---

> C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.1\bin/../include\w32api.h(186): warning C4005: '_EXTERN_C': マクロが再定義されました。
> C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/../../VC/INCLUDE\yvals.h(560): note: '_EXTERN_C' の以前の定義を確認してください
>
> C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.1\bin/../include\float.h(57): fatal error C1021: プリプロセッサ コマンド 'include_next' が無効です。

このパスにある`w32api.h`や`float.h`はGCC(MinGWかな？）向けのヘッダーファイルであり、Visual C++では使えません。syghさんが指摘されている通り正しく環境構築が行われていないようです。

Comment: CUDAは使いうべきではないと考え、GCCの方でコンパイラしたところ「C1021: プリプロセッサ コマンド 'include_next' が無効です」は消えました。ただhttps://pastebin.com/yfnJyuXMの方に大量の警告と少しのエラーが出てきました。このエラーも文字データなどがちゃんとしたものでないため起きているかもしれません。エディタはメモを使っており、プログラムはUnicodeで保存しています。

Comment: @ToxinCarnage さん、私は保存し直すべきではないという立場をとっています。「保存し直したら大量の警告が出てきました」と言われましても、残念ながらどうにもなりません。環境を構築し直してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: 私の説明の仕方が悪かったようです。保存はしなおしていません。無いヘッダファイルがあったので加えたところエラーが出ました。このようなエラーは正常というか異常なエラーなのでしょうか？https://pastebin.com/Lgf2L4E2プログラムのエラーというかヘッダファイルを加えた際に何かしらのミスがあってこのようなエラーが発生しているのかとも考えています。なんにしてもエラーを解読してみます。

Comment: すいませんvisual studioでの文字コードの変更の仕方がわからなかったので、メモ帳でUnicodeで保存して、ビルドしてみたのですが警告が消えません。ちなみに、文字コードがふさわしいものでないと見た目が間違いのないソースコードでも、コンパイラの際に文字コードの違いで構文的なエラーが出てしまうのでしょうか？

Comment: 警告はすべて消すことができました。ですがエラーがまだ出てしまいどうしてよいかわからずにいます。こちらがエラーですhttps://pastebin.com/FhdUMCaD　警告が消えたのに構文エラーがなぜ出るのかさっぱりわかりません。

Answer (score 0):

ヘッダファイル含め、ソースコードの記述にはどんなソフトを使用されていますか？さすがにメモ帳ということはないと思いますが、作成したヘッダファイル(*.h)の文字コードが932(Shift-JIS)で保存されているためコンパイルエラーになっているようです。

文字コードを指定して保存出来るエディタを使用して、ヘッダファイルやソースコードをUnicode(UTF-8)で保存し直してみてください。

参考：
[Windows向けのテキストエディタ(窓の杜)](https://forest.watch.impress.co.jp/library/nav/genre/offc/document_txteditor.html)
[Notepad++でファイルの文字コードを変更する](https://www.howtonote.jp/notepadplusplus/install/index7.html)

Comment: C4819で警告されているファイルは`c:\program files\nvidia gpu computing toolkit\cuda\v9.1\include`に置かれているものなので、質問者さんが書き換えたというわけではないと思いますし、保存し直すべきではないと思います。

Comment: メモ以外のエディタで行っていたのでメモに変えました。あのメモの文字コードの保存でunicodeとUTF-8のどちらかなのですが、どちらで保存すればいいのでしょうか？

Comment: おかげさまで文字に関するエラーは消えたのですが、「C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.1\bin/../include\float.h(57): fatal error C1021: プリプロセッサ コマンド 'include_next' が無効です。」だけがエラーとして出てきます。

Comment: こちらがエラーの表すヘッダフィルの中身です。https://pastebin.com/B7uamTNp（コードが長かったのでこちらに載せました。）

Answer (score 0):

もう解決しているようですが、一応書いておきます。OPENCVをCUDAでコンパイルするには、
ダウンロードしたCUDAのバージョンがVisualStudioのバージョンとマッチしているかをまず確認します。現時点のCUDA9.1では15.45までしか対応していません。バージョンが15.5以上になっていたら
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/installing-an-earlier-release-of-vs2017
運が良ければここに15.45のリンクが残ってますので現在のバージョンをアンインストールしてここからダウンロードできるインストーラーを使ってインストールしなおしてください。
インストールの追加のオプションで英語の言語パックもインストールしておきます。
ここまで出来たら、コントロールパネルを開いて地域を開き管理タブを選択して下の段のシステムロケールを変更ボタンを押して言語を英語（米国）にします。
再起動を求められますから素直に再起動してからCUDAを含めた構成でCMAKEをします。
このやり方でやればCUDAのヘッダーやソースコードをエディタで保存しなおしたりしなくてもコンパイルは通ります。
できたDLLなどはコードページをもとに戻しても使えます。

Comment: Visual Studio 15.5以降では過去バージョンのVisual C++が選択・インストール出来るようになっています。Visual Studio Installerにて **VC++ 2017 version 15.4 v14.11 toolset** を選択されるとCUDAが動作するバージョンを入手できるかと思います。その他にも設定は必要ですが。

Comment: その他の設定を説明します。CUDA_HOST_COMPILER の部分が、$(VCInstallDir)Tools/MSVC/$(VCToolsVersion)/bin/Host$(Platform)/$(PlatformTarget)となっていない場合は自分でCL.exeのパスを指定してあげなければなりません。C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.11.25503/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe こんな感じです。あと、CUDA_ARCH_BIN　を自分が使用するビデオカードに合わせないと書いてあるものすべてビルドするのでめちゃくちゃ時間がかかります。CUDA統合の部分は、ビルドするPCのロケール変更、対応ツールキット導入、あとは私が書いた追加の設定をやればとりあえずコンパイルできると思います。あとはユーザー個別のカスタマイズになります。